# CSS grid row should span all the way

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I use CSS grid in this example. It's not really that important what the grid contains in this case.

The container `.wrap` has a red background. I want the `aside` and `main` row to span all the way down to fill upp the `.wrap`. It means that the red background should no longer be seen, covered by gray and white.

As seen in this example I use `1fr` but that does not do much in this case. I've also tried `auto` but with no difference.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  background: green;
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                        "aside main"
                       "footer footer";
                       
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 48px 1fr 50px;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: black;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background: #333;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>Main</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `height: 100%` on `.content` as well, so that the grid fills the `.wrap` parent which sets the `height`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  background: green;
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                        "aside main"
                       "footer footer";
                       
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 48px 1fr 50px;
  height: 100%; /* Added */
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: black;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background: #333;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>Main</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, then this should be possible by adding `height:100%` to `.content` which will cause the `<aside>` and `<main>` elements to vertically expand to fill the `.wrap` element:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
/* Add this */
  height:100%;
  background: green;
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                        "aside main"
                       "footer footer";
                       
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 48px 1fr 50px;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: black;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background: #333;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>Main</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it setting height

```css
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .wrap {
      height: 300px;
      background: red;
    }

    .content {
      background: green;
      display: grid;

      grid-template-areas: "header header"
                            "aside main"
                           "footer footer";
                           
      grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 48px 1fr 50px;
    }

    header {
      grid-area: header;
      background: black;
    }

    aside {
      grid-area: aside;
      background: #333;
      height: 500px;
    }

    main {
      grid-area: main;
      background: #fff;
      color: #000;
      height: 500px;
    }

    footer {
      grid-area: footer;
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <header>Header</header>
        <aside>Aside</aside>
        <main>Main</main>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Setting the explicit `height: 500px` for `aside` and `main` is counter-intuitive to what `grid` is all about and not what OP wants.